# Difference between Mono.zip and Flux.zip in this particular case with flatMap

Tags: java, project-reactor

I would like to appreciate the different because right now both ways produce the same result.

```
Flux<String> draws = Flux.just("A", "B", "C");
        Flux<Tuple2<List<String>, List<String>>> monoZipFlux = draws.flatMap(draw->{
            Flux<String> source1 = getFirstSource(draw);
            Flux<String> source2 = getSecondSource(draw);
            return  Mono.zip(source1.collectList(), source2.collectList());
        });
        List<Tuple2<List<String>, List<String>>> firstExamples = monoZipFlux.collectList().block();
        for (Tuple2 firstExample : firstExamples) {
            System.out.println("firstExample.getT1(): " + firstExample.getT1());
            System.out.println("firstExample.getT2(): " + firstExample.getT2());
        }

        Flux<Tuple2<List<String>, List<String>>> fluxZipFlux = draws.flatMap(draw->{
            Flux<String> source1 = getFirstSource(draw);
            Flux<String> source2 = getSecondSource(draw);
            return Flux.zip(source1.collectList(), source2.collectList());
        });
        List<Tuple2<List<String>, List<String>>>  secondExamples = fluxZipFlux.collectList().block();
        for (Tuple2 secondExample : secondExamples) {
            System.out.println("secondExample.getT1(): " + secondExample.getT1());
            System.out.println("secondExample.getT2(): " + secondExample.getT2());
        }
```

What is the advantage/disadvantage for both ways in this particular case and which should I use?

Comment: I think you'll get the same result. What do you see when you run it?

Comment: Yes exactly i get same results. So that's why I am wondering what should I use, I couldn't appreciate the differences

Comment: As you need a single item as a result then use `Mono.zip`, there is no reason to use `Flux.zip` for a single item